# Gradle compiling .java inside jar files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm having a strange scenario where Gradle seems like it is attempting to compile ".java" files located inside of jar files I set as dependencies. I do something like this:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile fileTree(dir: './libs', include: ['*JarResources/Java/*.jar'])
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

...and I have a rather large list of jar dependencies. When I try to run my tests it fails in the compile stage where it cannot find symbols for the Java files tucked inside the jar files. Some of these jar dependencies are packaged with their source sitting next to the corresponding .class. I tried using an include filter in my source set to no avail.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/mypkg/other/**'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            include 'com/mypkg/test/**'
        }
    }
}
```

I can run the tests in IntelliJ 13 using its gradle-aware make without issue (here I am right clicking the unit tests and running them) as it is smart enough to build the dependency class path without passing the files to Javac but somehow the same build.gradle is failing from the command line. Is this a known issue where Gradle automatically passes dependencies to javac as it finds them in the Jar files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default behavior of the Java compiler (source path defaults to class path, files on source path get compiled). One way out is to explicitly set the source path to "nothing":

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-sourcepath", "''"]
}
```

PS: Not all tools/IDEs can deal with sources in Jars, so it's generally better to put them in a separate sources Jar.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! You saved my bacon with that tip! Unfortunately I don't have the ability to alter the structure of the dependencies. It's one of those "it was like that when I got it" scenarios. I wouldn't have found my way out of this one for a while!